# Questions on translation

Tags: grammaire

I'm learning French by myself reading Karl C. Sandburg's book French for Reading , and get lost on this line:

> Econome, elle mangeait avec lenteur, et recueillait du doigt sur la table les miettes de son pain, un de douze livres, cuit exprès pour elle, et qui durait vingt
>   jours.

What does it mean ? In particular I'm lost in 2 parts:

1. How come the structure is "recueillait du doigt sur la table les miettes de son pain"? 
   In English it's "... collect crumbs of her bread with her fingers on the table", "collect" could not lead 2 objects, there shall be a preposition ("**with**") before "her fingers" , isn't it?
   Or in French, it shall be "recueillait **à** du doigt sur la table les miettes de son pain", isn't it?
2. What does "un de douze livres" mean? "one of twelve books"? How come "son pain"/"her **bread**" links to **books**?

Below is the full text of the article, forgive me for any typos:

Un coeur simple

G. Flaubert -- "Trois Contes" (1877)

Pendant un demi-siècle, les bourgeoises de Pont-l'Evêque envièrent a Mme
Aubain sa servante Félicité.

Pour cent francs par an, elle faisait la cuisine et resta fidèle à sa maîtresse,
qui cependant n'était pas une personne agréable.

Elle (Mme Aubain) avait épousé un beau garçon sans fortune, mort au
commencement de 1809, en lui laissant deux enfants très jeunes avec une
quantité de dettes. 
Alors elle vendit tous ses immeubles, sauf la ferme de Toucques et la ferme de Geffosses, et elle quitta sa maison de Saint-Melaine pour en habiter une autre moins dispendieuse, ayant appartenu à ses ancêtres et placee derriere les halles. . . .

Félicité se levait des l'aube, pour ne pas manquer la messe, et travaillait
jusqu'au soir sans interruption; puis le diner étant fini, la vaisselle en
ordre et la porte bien close, elle enfouissait la bûche sous les cendres
et s'endormait devant l'âtre, son rosaire à la main. 
Personne dans les marchandages ne montrait plus d'entêtement. 
Quant à la propreté, le poli de ses casseroles faisait le désespoir des autres servantes. 
Econome, elle mangeait avec lenteur, et recueillait du doigt sur la table les miettes de son pain, un de douze livres, cuit exprès pour elle, et qui durait vingt
jours.

En toute saison elle portait un mouchoir d'indienne fixé dana le dos , par une épingle.

Son visage était maigre et sa voix aiguë. A vingt-cinq ans, on lui en donnait quarante. Dès la cinquantaine (50), elle ne montra plus aucun âge; et toujours silencieuse, la taille droite et les gestes mesurés, elle
semblait une femme en bois, fonctionnant d'une manière automatique.

Comment: I understand you had these two questions linked by your reading of Flaubert, but I have to say these are in fact (at least) two questions, not one. Consequence is, the title is awfully useless to anyone, which is a pity on a site like this one. I didn't vote to close, though. Tricky case if you ask me.

Comment: (Also, *un de douze livres* is just a literary omission of the word *pain*, it indeed refers to a twelve pounds bread.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elle recueillait du doigt sur la table les miettes de son pain**

That's how you can break down the sentence in order to understand it :

- Il y avait des miettes de pain sur la table.
- De son doigt elle recueillait les miettes.

The issue here is to understand the use of prepositon *de* in the sentence.

*De* here means "by means of" / "with". You could replace it with *avec* or *à l'aide de* but **not** with ***à***.

There were multiple questions in your question and @Nickstoy answered the others.

Answer (score 3):

I can help you with your 2nd question:  *livres*, like many other words in french, can have multiple meanings.

In this context, it means *pounds*, a weight measure unit.

- Je pèse 200 livres.  =   I weigh 200 pounds

Livres can also mean Books, as you mentioned in you question.

- La bibliothèque contient beaucoup de livres.  = The library contains many books.

It could also be the verb *to deliver*.

- Le facteur à livré mon colis aujourd'hui.  = The mailman delivered my package today.

For your first question, I'm not certain I understand it.  I will refine my answer if I can wrap my head around it.

Comment: It's interresting to note that nowadays, 1 livre = 500 grams in metric system, while 1 pound is slightly less, around 453 grams. About the first question, The OP quite doesn't understand that "du doigt" can mean "using your finger" (ramasser quelquechose du doigt) or "of the finger" (le bout du doigt), and would have expected something like "elle ramassait avec son doigt les miettes..." Which is kinda basic language that is of course not used by Flaubert.